is there a way to lock the viewport render resolution?
I'm checking shots in the viewport render but they look slightly different to the actual finished render. all the settings are the same, that's not the issue. it's because the viewport render uses screen space size where the actual render uses whatever resolution I've set. I think this is fine for a lot of things but I'm also a bit tired of waiting for something to finish rendering and then for it to begin again if I zoom in slightly to check something. Is there any way to lock this?
